# AttributeError: module 'comtypes.gen.SpeechLib' has no attribute 'ISpeechVoice'

Tags: python, text-to-speech

I want to use pyttsx3 in my code but I always have that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Romain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\Romain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 3, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\Romain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Romain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Romain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 52, in __init__
    self._driver = self._module.buildDriver(weakref.proxy(self))
  File "C:\Users\Romain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 30, in buildDriver
    return SAPI5Driver(proxy)
  File "C:\Users\Romain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 35, in __init__
    self._tts = comtypes.client.CreateObject('SAPI.SPVoice')
  File "C:\Users\Romain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 250, in CreateObject
    return _manage(obj, clsid, interface=interface)
  File "C:\Users\Romain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 188, in _manage
    obj = GetBestInterface(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Romain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 112, in GetBestInterface
    interface = getattr(mod, itf_name)
AttributeError: module 'comtypes.gen.SpeechLib' has no attribute 'ISpeechVoice'
```

And my code:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("This is a test")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Can you please help me ? (using Python 3.8.3 and Studio code)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60307452/pyttsx3-initialization-error-cant-use-pyttsx3

Comment: I tried with `engine = pyttsx3.init('dummy')`and now it just do nothing: no error and no voice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to reinstall pyttsx3 with another version and it worked (command:`pip uninstall pyttsx3`and `pip install pyttsx3==2.7`)

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises due to older version of `comtypes` (a default module required in `pyttsx3`) so no need to install older version of `pyttsx3`

Just type the following in cmd:

```sh
pip install --upgrade comtypes
```

Now you are good to go